# css dropdown menu moving page content

Tags: html, css

I have made a css dropdown menu out of only css and html. My problem is when I hover over the nav bar- my page content moves to the right. Then when I hover over the dropdown menu, the page content moves back to the left. I have not found anything that can help me so far. I have attached the relevant code below.

Please help me, and thank you

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
}


ul {
 float: left;
}

ul li {
 position: relative;
 list-style: none;
 float: left;
 line-height: 80px;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #c92d39;
}


ul li a{
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #c92d39;
 padding: 0 30px;
}


ul li a:hover {
 color: black;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c92d39;
}

ul li:hover ul {
 display: block;
}

ul li ul {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}


ul li ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #b2b2b2;
 color: #c92d39;
 border-bottom: none;
}

ul li ul li {
 font-size: 15px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 color: #c92d39;
 padding: 30px;
}

h2 {
 color: #c92d39;
 padding: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
}

p {
 padding: 0px 30px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}



#logo {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 padding: 0 51px 0 75px;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.page-body {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.wrapper {
 margin: 0 300px 0 300px;
 padding-left: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}

.footer {
 background-color: #cccccc;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
}

.empty_box {
 height: 1000px;
 width: 100%;
}

#contacts {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
 padding: 0 20px;
 border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#contacts:hover {
 border-top: 1px solid #c92d39;
}

#copyright {
 font-size: 10px;
 float: right;
 padding: 0px 30px 0 770px;
}

#copyright:hover {
 background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Basecode</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

 <body>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li id="logo">Cultural Asia</li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
     <a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">attraction1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">attraction2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">attraction3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="packages.html">Packages</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">package1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">package2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">package3</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="page-body">
   <div class="wrapper">
    <p>hi</p>    
    <div class="empty_box"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="contacts.html" id="contacts">Contact Details</a></li>
    <li id="copyright">Copyright Lachlan Dunn</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear your `floats`.

```css
.page-body {
    …
    clear: left;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

ul {
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #c92d39;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c92d39;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c92d39;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}

ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
  color: #c92d39;
  border-bottom: none;
}

ul li ul li {
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  color: #c92d39;
  padding: 30px;
}

h2 {
  color: #c92d39;
  padding: 5px 30px 10px 30px;
}

p {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#logo {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  padding: 0 51px 0 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.page-body {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  clear: left;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 300px 0 300px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
}

.empty_box {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

#contacts {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#contacts:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid #c92d39;
}

#copyright {
  font-size: 10px;
  float: right;
  padding: 0px 30px 0 770px;
}

#copyright:hover {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="logo">Cultural Asia</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="attractions.html">Attractions</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">attraction1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">attraction2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">attraction3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="packages.html">Packages</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">package1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">package2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">package3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div class="page-body">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>hi</p>
    <div class="empty_box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="contacts.html" id="contacts">Contact Details</a></li>
    <li id="copyright">Copyright Lachlan Dunn</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was just wondering why this fixes the problem, so that I can avoid doing it in the future.

Comment: @LachlanDunn Here's a [quick read](https://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/) that should help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you add a bottom-border to element which pushes paragraph out of its position. do

```
ul li a:hover {
    color: black;   
}
```

instead of

```
 ul li a:hover {
        color: black;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c92d39;
    }
```

or if you really want that border check out css  box-sizing property documentation